# Debian max_sectors_kb reverts upon use?

Tags: debian, iscsi

I am setting a value in `/sys/block/xxx/queue/max_sectors_kb` in order to try and resolve an iSCSI IO site limit bug and have found the value to revert to its default `32767` as soon as the iSCSI disk is used.

I am setting both manually and with udev rules but the same thing happens, my value of `512` gets replaced again with `32767` which causes IO errors and failure when I am creating a new VM on the iSCSI disk.

Comment: Can you please add the debian version?

Comment: Can you check what VPD block limits your device reports, using sg_inq /dev/sda -p bl (for the correct device) What type of iSCSI target is this? Is it possible that you are hit by the bug fixed here: https://marc.info/?l=linux-scsi&m=142958776223667&w=2

Comment: How do you create the VM? E.g. Openstack, vmware?

Comment: Did you check the log?

Comment: I will check the VPD command today. The target is a HP P2000 iSCSI SAN.

Comment: I get this:


root@apollo12:/etc/apt# sg_inq /dev/sde -p bl
VPD INQUIRY: Block limits page (SBC)
  Maximum compare and write length: 1 blocks
  Optimal transfer length granularity: 1 blocks
  Maximum transfer length: 65535 blocks
  Optimal transfer length: 2048 blocks
  Maximum prefetch, xdread, xdwrite transfer length: 0 blocks
  Maximum unmap LBA count: 65536
  Maximum unmap block descriptor count: 1
  Optimal unmap granularity: 1
  Unmap granularity alignment valid: 0
  Unmap granularity alignment: 0

Comment: Are you using multipath ? Multipath devices don't have their own queue, and I have already seen settings being automatically inherited from the multipath device.

Comment: According to this [Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/open-iscsi/6bp5FMM8DwI), as of Linux kernel 3.19, the max_sectors_kb value always is 32767 for any LUN. Please check your kernel version by `uname -r` to see if you are affected.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been seen before:

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/troubles-iscsi-and-max_sectors_kb.25750/

It seems it can be solved on a udev script but you must consider:

1. udev script might interpret redirection symbol ">" as a command parameter; then just call a regular bash script from the udev script and set the value there.
2. when the disk is "plugged/first used" the value is created then the corresponding udev script must be sure that it does its job "after" the disk connection process is finished.

reference:
https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/12155562